# Reusing variadic templates for constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, generics, constructor, variadic-templates

How can one store a variadic template to enable reuse in later instances?

Code Example:

```
template <typename T, typename ...initArgs>
Collection_class {

   std::vector<T> storage; 
   initArgs ...constructorArguments;

   Collection_class<T, initArgs>(initArgs... args) {
       constuctorArguments = args;
   }

   void CreateInstance() {
        storage.emplace(constructorArguments); 
   }
}
```

Is there any way you can store a varidic template as an object/collection that would enable you to reuse it, in this case for a constructor?

I have seen people storing the arguments in a `std::tuple` however I am unsure how I could use that in a generic class.

Much thanks, JJ.

Comment: You may like [`make_from_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple), coming to C++17 near you.

Comment: Didn't you ask that already today?

Comment: I did not ask this today or any day prior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acheive this by storing the arguments in a tuple:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T, int index, typename ...initArgs>
struct VectorInit {
  static void append(std::vector<T> & dst, 
                     std::tuple<initArgs...> const& args) {
    VectorInit<T, index-1, initArgs...>::append(dst, args);
    dst.emplace_back(std::get<index>(args));
  }
};

template<typename T, typename ...initArgs>
struct VectorInit<T, 0, initArgs...> {
  static void append(std::vector<T> & dst, 
                     std::tuple<initArgs...> const& args) {
    dst.emplace_back(std::get<0>(args));
  }
};

template <typename T, typename ...initArgs>
class Collection_class {
   std::vector<T> storage; 
   std::tuple<initArgs...> init_args;

public:
   Collection_class(initArgs... args)
     : init_args(args...) {
   }

   void CreateInstance() {
     storage.reserve(sizeof...(initArgs));
     VectorInit<T, sizeof...(initArgs)-1, initArgs...>::append(storage, init_args);
   }
};

int main() {
    Collection_class<double, float, int> test(1.2f, 4);
    test.CreateInstance();
}
```

**Edit:** `CreateInstance()` can be implemented by recursively peeling each element of the tuple. I did it from `sizeof...(args)` to 0, which is why the recursion happens before the `emplace_back`.

There's probably a neater way to do this with parameter pack expansions, but this is a simple enough case that I find the template specialization route to be simpler.

Comment: That's not "forwarding".

Comment: Oh right, you are correct, (so used to templated constructors...)

Comment: The OP is also contructing an object in a vector with those parameters.  Can you show them how they would do that now that they are in a `std::tuple`?

Comment: If you can utilized an `std::tuple` to initialize objects of unknown types I will vote as best answer. Upvoted @NathanOliver

Comment: Updated the answer with an implementation of `CreateInstance()`, sorry for the ommision.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply let the `std::vector` handle that:

```
template <typename T>
Collection_class {

   std::vector<T> storage; 
public:
   Collection_class<T>(std::initializer_list<T> initargs) : storage(initargs) {
   }
}
```

Note the deferred `CreateInstance()` won't be necessary anymore.

---

The `initArgs` variadic template parameters would let your `Collection_class` instantiations *"explode"* for any possible combination of parameters. That's certainly not what you actually want.

Comment: This requires you use the same type for all initialization arguments.

Comment: @AndyG The `std::vector<T> storage;` requires that anyway. IIRC OP asked the same question today (as mentioned in my comment), and all they wanted was to call the constructor like `Collection_class<int> c(2,5,3,1,42);`

Comment: This question is a bit broader than that. They are indeed asking for a tuple approach. Whether they have ten thousand initialization arguments or not is a design question. I don't think it will "explode" for rational use cases.

Comment: @AndyG In a review for embedded code, it wouldn't pass my votes.

Comment: @user0042 I haven't asked this question today, I don't know why you keep saying that. 

No I don't want to initialize a sum of integers. I am writing a collection class (that will be used generically) which will allow (the programmer) choose default constructor arguments. (Not using the default constructor)

Comment: Also the arguments may or may not be of the same type hence why I am not using a 'std::vector<T>'

Comment: @JosephFranciscus Then you probably best edit your question and post an example how you want to use that. I'm pretty sure I've seen a similar question today, but sure that could have been one of your fellow students.

Comment: I have posted already posted a code example detailing my intentions. 

I need something similar to... `std::vector<T>(unsigned n_elements, variadic_args... args)`.

However whenever my collection class grows it needs to add an object of type `T` with the same constructor parameters as used in the `variadic_args.... args`

My issue is finding a way to effectively store the variadic_arguments that would allow me to reuse them in T's constructor (when I need to call it again). 
Your current answer is not relevant to my question.